# is there a sublime command for removing the line the cursor is on

Tags: sublimetext2

what Ctrl+d would do in VI
I found the command duplicate_line and managed to create a shortcut for it like so:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+y"], "command": "duplicate_line"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> should remove current line.

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+k"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/Default/Delete Line.sublime-macro"} },
```

If you are using VI mode, <kbd>d</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> in command mode should remove current line, too.

Comment: where is this key binding? I can't find it anywhere though it works like a charm :)

Comment: @elewinso Check the default key bindings: Preferences -> Key Bindings - Default.